# How to make list variables using an excel data set in R (R Newie)

Tags: r, list, relational-database, relationship

I'm trying to map some relationships. I have an excel sheet with the first column being the account ID number and the following columns have the ID numbers of related accounts. If I had access at work I would build a relational database and start there but I don't and I'm not sure that making the relational database would help with the application I need to write. I would like to write a loop that takes the account number in column 1 and relates it to each column that has a related account in it (it varies depending on which account from one related account to a dozen). My thinking is some kind of list variable where each account ID works as a unique identifier for all their related accounts.

I spent a bunch of time reading about the theory of list variables and it seems like exactly what I need. Is that something I can do in R?[example of spreadsheet...not the real one because its confidential](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omNwj.png) [Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IESFS.png)

Comment: An example of a desired output would be nice to have.

Comment: Sorry the output I want would be something like:
1111| 1211 1212
My goal is once I have the relationships between the accounts mapped I will be able to run a report on a large trial balance sheet looking for oddities between the first account and their listed related accounts (limits, missing balances, proportions, etc).

Comment: Put a link in the OP with how I imagine the desired output is supposed to look @denisafonin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is your data:

```
df

# A tibble: 3 x 6
     ID Related1 Related2 Related3 Related4 Related5
  <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1  1111     1211     1212       NA       NA       NA
2  2222     1211     1212     1333       NA       NA
3  3333     4210     5689     8756     6245     5151
```

Now this i think is what you want:

```
df %>%
  gather(key = key, value = Related, -ID) %>%
  select(-key) %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  arrange(ID, Related)

# A tibble: 10 x 2
      ID Related
   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1  1111    1211
 2  1111    1212
 3  2222    1211
 4  2222    1212
 5  2222    1333
 6  3333    4210
 7  3333    5151
 8  3333    5689
 9  3333    6245
10  3333    8756
```

Correct?

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I want to do to my worksheet and then I suppose uniquely identify each individual relationship (which I guess it's doing by numbering them). Do I have to use the header names or can I just do something like column 1 for ID and then col 2:27 for the related?

Comment: You actually just need to change -ID to -.[[1]]  this will be enough

Comment: Thanks so much. I really appreciate your help. I am getting an error though: 
> data %>%
+   gather(key = key, value = .[[4:27]], -.[[1]]) %>%
+   select(-key) %>%
+   na.omit() %>%
+   arrange(.[[1]], .[[4:27]])
Error in data %>% gather(key = key, value = .[[4:27]], -.[[1]]) %in% select(-key) %>%  : 
  could not find function "%>%"
I googled it and installed the tidyr package but it's still not recognizing it.

Comment: Run these: install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)

Comment: Still getting the same error and when I delete the pipe operator it tells me it can't find the function "gather" but I installed dplyr, tidyr, tidyverse, and magrittr. Any suggestions?

Comment: Substitute .[[4:27]] for Related (or any other word really). Just use my code and only substitute ID with .[[1]]

Comment: The logic of this code is that you are taking all columns apart from ID (hence, -ID, or -.[[1]]) and turn values from these columns into a variable called 'Related'

Comment: Now I'm getting this error:  Must supply a symbol or a string as argument

here's my code ( i did it without pipes):
bsadac <-readxl::read_xlsx("Data.xlsx")
gathered.bsadac <- gather(bsadac,key, .[[5:13]], -.[[1]], na.rm = TRUE)
clean.gathered.bsadac <- select(gathered.bsadac, -key)
sorted.bsadac <- arrange(clean.gathered.bsadac, .[[1]])

Comment: bsadac <-readxl::read_xlsx("Data.xlsx") 
gathered.bsadac <- gather(bsadac,key, Related, -.[[1]], na.rm = TRUE) 
clean.gathered.bsadac <- select(gathered.bsadac, -key) 
sorted.bsadac <- arrange(clean.gathered.bsadac, .[[1]])

Comment: I really appreciate all the time you've taken to help me. If I do well at this internship I get a real job post grad school so, seriously, thank you. I tried just copying your code and I keep getting the error '("Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : object '.' not found")'
The error comes after the gathered.bsadac<- gather.... line of code. Is there a version or package im missing to let it know that .[[1]] means column 1 in the dataframe?

Comment: I went back into the data and re-named column 1 something that wasn't also the name of a data frame and the code worked perfectly. Again thank you so much. You're a hero.

Comment: Glad to hear you figured it out :)